# Not receiving GCM notification on Android 6.0.1

Tags: android

Not receiving GCM notification on **Android 6.0.1** on **some devices** but when i *restart device the pending GCM notification comes* immediately

Comment: Also check that this isn't related to Doze mode (https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html)

Comment: I have already checked the doze mode and it says to add priority, i have done that too but didn't help.   BTW i am using **'play-services-gcm:8.4.0'**

Comment: We have moved from GCM to FCM but still same problem...